# how can force intellij to work with specific TLS version?

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea

got this annoying error when trying to connect new local mssql data source in intellij .
( getting same error when trying to connect from code )

[08S01] The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.". ClientConnectionId:ffbe4d7e-70b5-4123-ad9a-36decc62858a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.

some details :

- all mssql services are running .
- intellij 2019.3 (can connect to remote mssql but cannot to one defined locally )
- mssql installed locally 2014
- project jdk jdk1.8.0_241
- mssql driver - 7.4.1
- spring-jdbc:5.1.2
- connection string - jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=local-test

another thing :
i got this error when trying to connect to remote mssql and by adding the port the issue was fixed ( doesnt work locally ) .

Thanks .

Comment: Does running the app with the following flag help? `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: And the same flag with only the TLS protocol supported by the client? TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2, or maybe both. If you use it with the unsupported value too, the app might be picking that one and that's why the connection is failing.

Comment: in 'Data source and Driver' windows im selecting my data source project and at the advance tab im setting 'sslProtocol' to TLSv1.1 . also at the same tab im at the bottom  im setting vm option -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1 - but still same error mwssage .

Comment: SQL Server 2014 supports TLS 1.1 and [TLS 1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server). Have you installed any service packs or cumulative updates?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ummm no i didnt ... but how come i can connect to remote db with same version - and wont get that error ?